# Friendly Names in linking database, add database column or use converter in application?

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database-design, mvvm

I have a WPF application using the MVVM pattern and MVVM Light Tookkit that is accesing a MSSQL server.  Below would be a sample database (the database I have is more complex):

```
Employee Table:
|Name          | ShipToLocation
---------------|--------------------
|John          | 1

ShipToLocation Table:
|Code | CityName 
------|------------------
| 1   | New York
```

I have used EntityFramwork to Create Objects out of my database tables.  The problem I am having is in my program now, I am having to use a lot of IValueConverters like such:

```
    <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" ItemsSource="{Binding Employees}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedItem="{Binding ThisEmployee}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IntToShipTo}">
                                <Binding Path="VendorCode" Mode="OneWay"/>
                                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}" Path="DataContext.ShipToLocations"/>
                            </MultiBinding>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In my ViewModel there is a property called Employees that holds a list of Emplyoyee, and a property called ShipToLocations that has a list of all Ship To Locations. I have to use the RelativeSource in order to access the ShipToLocations Property since the ItemSource of the ListBox is set to "Employees", which is causing design time view problems

I have this kind of linking going on in alot of places, and I will need to make a converter for each one.  This seems like alot of overhead, and a Unit Testing nightmare.

What I was wondering was, would it be bad practice to, in my Employee Table, add a column called ShipToFriendlyName, and then attach a trigger on the ShipToLocation field that will update the frienldy name when the int is changed.  This would avoid the need to be doing database calls every time I need to find out what the friendly name of the Integer is.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I was wondering was, would it be bad practice...

Yes, that would be very bad practice.

Comment: SQL Server is a relational database exactly because of the power of its relational joins.  Entity Frameworks can be a little longwinded, but that's because they usually have tools to generate them, so you shouldn't try to simplify your framework, by reducing the "proper" relationships in your database.

Comment: So I should just stick to the ValueConverters, or is there a better way to do this

Comment: What I did as a solution is add a read only property on my EntityObject called DisplayShipTo, and when the Employee is Selected I do a linq to the database context to grab the DisplayName.  Thank you for helping me avoid a bad practice.

Comment: Your welcome... A lot of bad practice is only so common because of the short term benefits it seems to offer when your project is small.  Only through experience do programmers recognize bad practice, that's why it is called practice :)